# XML namespace inheritance

Tags: java, xml, xsd, axis, xml-namespaces

Let's say I have following xsd schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="kom">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="um">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="odd" 
                                  type="TypKod" 
                                  use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="version" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:normalizedString">
                    <xs:length value="3"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="1.0"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="od" type="TypKod" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="TypKod">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:normalizedString">
        <xs:length value="2" fixed="true"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="01"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And I have following soap UI envelope:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     
                  xmlns:b="http://xml.daniel.pl/b" 
                  xmlns:c="http://xml.daniel.pl/c"     
                  xmlns:xm="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <b:execute>
         <b:date>2013-12-06T12:32:41.106+01:00</:date>
         <b:pay>
            <b:text>
               <p:kom xmlns:p="http://daniel/p" version="1.0" od="01">
                   <um odd="01"/>
               </p:kom>
            </b:text>
         </b:payload>
      </b:execute>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The question is, shouldn't it be 
            `<p:um odd="01"/>` 
instead of 
            `<um odd="01"/>`
?
Element um belongs to namespace 'p' but i don't know how to prepare schema.

In code generated by axis I have:

```
   if (reader.isStartElement() && new javax.xml.namespace.QName("","um").equals(reader.getName()))
```

so there is empty string before 'um'. How can I make it to put there my namespace 'p' without manual modification of classes generated by axis?

When I put `<p:um odd="01"/>` in the envelope I get:
`Caused by: java.lang.Exception: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://daniel/p}um`

Comment: I think you need to add `targetNamespace="http://daniel/p"` on the `<xs:schema>` tag.

Comment: thanks. I added  following: `targetNamespace="http://daniel/p" xmlns:p="http://daniel/p"` and xsd seems to be ok. Tomorrow I will regenerate java classes and I will try to run the full process.